# What kind of solutions magento 2 have for global product codes except SKU like GTIN?

Tags: magento2, unique-constraint

We want to have one solution for products for unique global codes. Is there any solutions in magento for this to create GTIN codes or any other kind of Globally accepted unique codes?

Comment: What about product Id?

Comment: We need some globally accepted unique codes.